# How to Store Array value in table column in mySql using java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, liferay

hello i am trying to retrieve data in two result set. then i have store in both resultset to String Array, after this process i have to store my String array to another table how to so this kindly tell me..

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.
         getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lportal", "root", "ubuntu123");
    PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) con.
         prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM  Testi_Testimonial where subject = ?");
    stmt.setString(1, search);
    stmt.execute();
    rs = (ResultSet) stmt.getResultSet();
    while (rs.next()) {
      anArray[i] = rs.getString("subject");
      System.out.println(anArray[i]);
      i++;
      count++;
    }
    PreparedStatement stmt1 = (PreparedStatement) con.
         prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Testi_Testimonial where subject != ?");
    stmt1.setString(1, search);
    stmt1.execute();
    rs1 = (ResultSet) stmt1.getResultSet();
    while (rs1.next()) {
      anArray[i] = rs1.getString("subject");
      System.out.println(anArray[i]);
      i++;
      count++;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("problem in connection");
}
```

Please tell me how should I store my array to `Temp` table? my "Temp" table has column `subject` I want to store `myArray` to `subject` column... kindly tell me how to  do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this after getting resultset in rs:

```
   PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into temp values(?)");
    i=0;
   while(rs.next())
    {
      st.setString(1,anArray[i]);
      st.executeUpdate();
      i++;
    }
```

Comment: in which table this will store?

Comment: i have "subject" column in my temp table.. and i want to store my array to this column how to do?

Comment: temp table as mentioned in query

Comment: PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into Testi_TestimonialTemp(subject) values(?)");

Comment: ya it is,if you have Testi_TestimonialTemp table

Comment: i have this table but i cant store myArray value to the table column

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28651/discussion-between-rajan-and-mahesh-patidar)

Answer (score 1):

You just iterate the arrayList. You got the subject List as respective.

```
public class TestArrayList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*create two arrayList*/
        List<String> tempOneList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vijay", "root", "root");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  subjecttable");

            while (res.next()) {
                tempOneList.add(res.getString("subject"));
            }

            ResultSet resOne = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  subjecttabletwo");
            while (resOne.next()) {
                tempOneList.add(resOne.getString("subject"));
            }
            System.out.println("temp/List>>--" + tempOneList.size());
            for(int i=0;i<tempOneList.size();i++){
                System.out.println(tempOneList.get(i));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("problem in connection");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PreparedStatement ps = 
    (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into temp values(?)");

j=0;
while(rs.next())
{
    ps.setString(1,anArray[j]);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    j++;
}
```

Comment: but i want to store my array to table column i have write my query like following is this perfect? my table is name is temp_testimonial and column name is subject  i want to store myArray value to "Subject" 

          PreparedStatement st = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into Testi_TestimonialTemp(subject) values(?)");
          i=0;
         while(rs.next())
          {
            st.setString(1,anArray[i]);
            st.executeUpdate();
            i++;
          }
          
   }

Comment: PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into temp_testimonial values(?)"); i=0; while(rs.next()) { st.setString(1,anArray[i]); st.executeUpdate(); i++; } }                                                                   wtite ? in subject field